# Possible variable hoisting issue

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Consider this JS (which is run at the end of the `body` and causing an error)

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    var div = document.getElementById("hook"),
        ul = div.firstElementChild,
        last_li = ul.lastElementChild;

    alert(div) // alerts "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined"  

})();
```

I then removed the commas and added the `var` keyword, but received a similar error (**it's not the HTML**):

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    var div = document.getElementById("hook");
    var ul = div.firstElementChild;
    var last_li = ul.lastElementChild;

    alert(div) // alerts "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastElementChild' of undefined " 

})();
```

The only way it works is by adding the `alert()` statement directly after the `div` assignment. I'm assuming this has relevance to variable hoisting but am not experienced enough to know for sure.

Can someone give a quick synopsis of variable hoisting and what may be going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your *entire* page?  Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/MDRrL/

Comment: You can just Google hoisting, but here's a description: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html There doesn't seem to be any variable hoisting going on here, and the code works just fine as is for me.

Comment: Technically hoisting IS going here BUT it isn't having an effect on anything here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not hoisting.

What's happening here is the following:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    // this returns an element otherwise the next line would not work
    // that means the element is found in the DOM
    var div = document.getElementById("hook"), 
        // this returns the value `undefined` or `null` 
        ul = div.firstElementChild,
        // this is a TypeError, since `ul` is undefined
        last_li = ul.lastElementChild;

    alert(div) // we never actually get to this line
})();
```

It's possible that the Element you have has no Elements in it (maybe just text nodes?)

Here is a [fiddle reproducting the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/Bq63R/).

Here is a [fiddle where it works](http://jsfiddle.net/Bq63R/1/).

Comment: Thank you. I did have children elements but they were commented out -- after removing the comments it works as expected.